# Is there a better way to structure an Angular 15 reactive form with inputs populating from an api?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms, rxjs-observables

Angular 15 Reactive Form using FormGroup

I am going through the docs trying to build a form with 4 inputs that populate with GET data, and update on submit via PUT. And it works. But it seems verbose and I wonder if there is a better way.

Here are my variables and the constructor:

```
  adminForm: FormGroup;
  parameters$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(
    @Inject("environment") public environment: IEnvironment,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private adminService: AdminService
  ) { }
```

and ngOnInit:

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.adminForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      pendingTimeout: ['', Validators.required],
      readyTimeout: ['', Validators.required],
      processingTimeout: ['', Validators.required],
      activeTimeout: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.parameters$ = this.adminService.getParameters();

    this.parameters$.subscribe(p => {
      console.log('p', p);
      this.f['activeTimeout'].setValue(p[0].value);
      this.f['pendingTimeout'].setValue(p[1].value);
      this.f['processingTimeout'].setValue(p[2].value);
      this.f['readyTimeout'].setValue(p[3].value);
    })
  }
```

A getter, to make the html less verbose:

```
  get f()
    {
        return this.adminForm.controls;
    }
```

and the submit method, configured so it returns to the API in the proper format:

```
submit() {
    if (!this.adminForm.valid) {
      return;
    }
    console.log(this.adminForm.value);
    this.adminService.putParameters([
      {
        "name": "ActiveTimeout",
        "value": this.adminForm.value.activeTimeout
      },
      {
        "name": "PendingTimeout",
        "value": this.adminForm.value.pendingTimeout
      },
      {
        "name": "ProcessingTimeout",
        "value": this.adminForm.value.processingTimeout
      },
      {
        "name": "ReadyTimeout",
        "value": this.adminForm.value.readyTimeout
      }
    ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a model class with a constructor to receive the result parameters, then use this Class Object to set the result instead of using the formControl['control'].value
A example would be like:

```
//In a separated class
export class AdminModel {
  public pendingTimeout: number;
  public readyTimeout: number;
  public processingTimeout: number;
  public activeTimeout: number;

 constructor(
        pendingTimeout: number,
        readyTimeout: number,
        processingTimeout: number,
        activeTimeout: number
){
            this.pendingTimeout = pendingTimeout,
            this.readyTimeout= readyTimeout,
            this.processingTimeout= processingTimeout,
            this.activeTimeout= activeTimeout
}
```

//in your component class

```
  adminForm: FormGroup;
  admin: any;
  parameters$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(
    @Inject("environment") public environment: IEnvironment,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private adminService: AdminService
  ) { }


ngOnInit() {
    this.adminForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      pendingTimeout: ['', Validators.required],
      readyTimeout: ['', Validators.required],
      processingTimeout: ['', Validators.required],
      activeTimeout: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.parameters$ = this.adminService.getParameters();

    this.parameters$.subscribe(p => {
      admin = new AdminModel(p[0].value,p[1].value,p[2].value,p[3].value);
    })
  }
```

I thinks is less verbose, the cons are the duplicated classes, but it's easyer to read and understand like that. I hope it helps :)

Comment: A simple function inside the component makes the work :)

Answer (score 1):

Always we repeat similar code we need think if it's good or not create a function.

```
//function that return a formGroup
createGroup(data:any=null)
{
   data=data || {pendingTimeout: '',
                 readyTimeout: '',
                 processingTimeout:'',
                 activeTimeout:''}

   return this.formBuilder.group({
      pendingTimeout: [data.pendingTimeout, Validators.required],
      readyTimeout: [data.readyTimeout, Validators.required],
      processingTimeout: [data.processingTimeout, Validators.required],
      activeTimeout: [data.activeTimeout, Validators.required]
    });
}
```

we can use

```
   this.adminForm=this.createGroup(); //<--an empty FormGroup
```

Or

```
   this.parameters$.subscribe(p=>{
      const data={
        activeTimeout: p[0].value,
        pendingTimeout: p[1].value,
        processingTimeout: p[2].value,
        readyTimeout: p[3].value
      }
      this.adminForm=this.createGroup(data)
    })
```